# I created a small POM framework in selenium but it doesnt seem to be recognizing my locators in the Test and also multiple browsers are opened

Tags: selenium-webdriver, page-objects, page-factory

Here are the details:

Question 1 : When I run my test, locators are not identified from the locators file? why? But when I added the driver.findElement(By.) in my test , it identifies though.

Question 2 : From my base class , I see 2 chrome browsers opened while running my tests? what changes are needed to fix that?

I have the below files :

**Base.java** - where my chrome driver is instantiated

```
public abstract class Base {

 @BeforeClass
 public static void setUp() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }

 @AfterClass
 public static void tearDown() {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", path);
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
 }

}
```

**locators.java:** Contains pagelevel element locators

```
public class sockLocators {
    // header text
    @FindBy(xpath = "//h1")
    public static WebElement socksHeader;
}
```

**TestCaseclass.java**

```
@Test
    public class SockTests extends Base {    
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    @Test
   public void verifyTitle() throws InterruptedException {    
        JungleSockCheckoutPage.navigateTo(driver);  
        //does not identify my locator  
        Assert.assertTrue(CheckoutPage.isPageTitleCorrect(driver));    
}
```

**Checkoutpage.java**

```
//verify page title
    public static boolean isPageTitleCorrect(WebDriver driver){
        if(driver.getTitle().contains(JS_CHECKOUT_PAGE_TITLE)){
            return true;
        }    
        else{    
            return false;
        }    
    }
```

Can you please help?

Comment: could you format your question so that we could read your code more easily? Also what do you mean by _locators file_?

Comment: Why are you creating driver in after class , remove that. Define driver as a global variable

Comment: You have created multiple instance of webdriver. Instead of creating multiple webdriver create singleton class and use the instance of singleton every where you want.

Comment: @PDHide - If I define as a global variable instead of in AfterClass - it throws and error saying that System.setproperty cannot be identified, hence I had to chage it as localvariable in before and afterclass. Is there any other way to do it? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

@ Alexey R - Locators file is nothing but my page object file where all my webelements are defined page wise.

OK.. will try using a singleton class and see if that helps!! Will keep you posted. Thanks all for the reply.

Comment: @Seluser public static webdriver driver = null

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want to use the [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) `@FindBy` annotation you also need to initialize them with `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);`.
2. Actually you create 3 browsers, but one gets closed instantly in `tearDown`. Everytime you use `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` it starts a new browser. You should store 1 driver instance as a global variable or in your test-context and reuse that everywhere else.

See the example here: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/getting-started-with-page-object-pattern-for-your-selenium-tests

Comment: I initialized using PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

Comment: +1 - and to be clear - **a new browser window for each test is the expected, default and desired behavior**

Comment: Otherwise tests start interacting with each and you get dependency hell.  YOu have to address setup, but you have to do it within each test

Answer (score 0):

@PDHide - If I define as a global variable instead of in AfterClass - it throws and error saying that System.setproperty cannot be identified, hence I had to chage it as localvariable in before and afterclass. Is there any other way to do it? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

@ Alexey R - Locators file is nothing but my page object file where all my webelements are defined page wise.

OK.. will try using a singleton class and see if that helps!! Will keep you posted. Thanks all for the reply.